# Highcharts v3.0.1 problems with rotating data labels in IE8 and jQuery v1.7.1

Tags: highcharts

Note: unless otherwise specified, all line numbers and source refer to the file highcharts.src.js as obtained from http://code.highcharts.com/3/highcharts.src.js on May 13th, 2013.

---

**Summary:**

It seems that in the specific case of rendering a column chart with IE8, Highcharts 3.0.1, and jQuery 1.7.1, there is a problem if you specify plotOptions.column.dataLabels.rotation to be a truthy value (something other than undefined or zero).  As best I can tell, this combination of factors causes somebody (Highcharts, jQuery?) to atempt to animate the "align" property, with unpleasant results. I have tried to re-create this in a Fiddle, but my simple case works. This appears to be because IE9 does not exercise the problem code path, and jsFiddle doesn't work under IE8, so I can't test there.

Here's the fiddle anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/Wr9wX/6/

As a side-note, these column charts fail with the same error with Highcharts v2.3.3. I had originally written v2.3.3 did not fail, but subsequent testing revealed that v2.3.3 fails as well. My production page renders correctly if I comment out line 13950 in highcharts.js, thereby preventing it from attempting to animate the 'align' property.

I have since been able to create a stand-alone test page that reproduces the problem. The key is the call to chart.setSize(width, height, animate).  The render fails if animate = true.  Interestingly, the render does not fail if the built-in reflow logic is handling the resize. Code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="highcharts-container" 
       id="highcharts-2" 
       style='z-index: 0; position: relative; text-align: left; line-height: normal; height: 100%;width: 100%; font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height: 100%; font-size: 12px; overflow: hidden;'>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;

    var render = function(id) {
       var foo;
       var chartSpec = {
         credits: false,
         chart: {
           animation: false,
           renderTo: id,
           type: 'column'
         },
         xAxis: {
           categories: ['Jan']
         },
         plotOptions: {
           series: {animation:false},
           column: {
             pointPadding: 0.2,
             borderWidth: 0,
             dataLabels: {
               rotation: -75,
               align: 'left',
               enabled: true
             }
           }
         },
         series: [{
           data: [29.9] 
         }]
       };

       foo = new Highcharts.Chart(chartSpec, function (chart) {
           chart.setSize(800, 600, true); // <====== fails here
       });
     };

    $(function () {
      render('highcharts-2');
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**The Gory Details:**

I am accessing highcharts via jQuery v1.7.1, and I have upgraded from Highcharts v2.3.3 to v3.0.1.  Our application worked fine under Highcharts v2.3.3, but fails with Highcharts v3.0.1. Under v3.0.1 and IE8 (Browser Mode: "IE8"; Document Mode: "IE8 Standards"), I get an "invalid argument" from the Highcharts extend() function:

```
/**
 * Extend an object with the members of another
 * @param {Object} a The object to be extended
 * @param {Object} b The object to add to the first one
 */
function extend(a, b) {
var n;
if (!a) {
    a = {};
}
for (n in b) {
    a[n] = b[n];   <------ fails here
}
return a;
}
```

I get failures under two conditions: one where n = one of ('top', 'left') and one where n = 'textAlign'.

In the failure case where n is one of ('top', 'left'), then a[n] = "<number>px" (where <number> represents a valid squence of numeric characters; e.g., "100px"), and b[n] = "NaNpx".

When n = "textAlign", then a[n] = "" and b[n] is a string whose value is the source code for a function with the string "NaN" appended to it.  The function that provided this source appears to be the align() function  starting at line 2720 in highcharts.src.js.  The error message is also different in this case: "Could not get the textAlign property. Invalid Argument"

I spent some time searching on this issue, of course, but all that taught me was that extend() can fail for a variety of reasons, depending on the values of a, b and n; no surprise there.

I then spent a few hours sleuthing up and down the call stack. What I found was that, in the animate() function in the Highcharts adaptor for jQuery, line 1408 executes as:

```
$el.animate(params, options);
```

which dissapears in to jQuery, emerging back into Highcharts in the init() method (line 1090) of that same adaptor.  In the block of code starting at 1138:

```
return elem.attr ? // is SVG element wrapper
       elem.attr(fx.prop, fn === 'cur' ? UNDEFINED : fx.now) : // apply the SVG wrapper's method
       base.apply(this, arguments); // use jQuery's built-in method
```

Interestingly, although I render four different types of chart (bar, column, pie, and scatter), only the column chart fails.  All column charts I attempt to render fail, regardless of which of my datasets I am charting.

Okay, it fails in animate(); turn animation off for the chart.  Still broken.  Look at the call stack again: hmmm; still coming in through animate.  Why?

Investigation shows that rotating the data labels still involves animate(), even if the chart render is not animated, per se.  Comment out the rotation propery in plotOptions.column.dataLabels, and now it works.

Here are the breaking plotOptions:

```
    plotOptions: {
      series: {},
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          rotation: -75,
          align: 'left'            
        }
      }
    }
```

It doesn't seem to matter what the value of rotation is.  If it has a "truthy" value, the render breaks.  If it is undefined, there is no problem.

So, create a Fiddle. Fiddle renders correctly; with or without rotation.  Realize that I am a moron, because I am runnning the Fiddle under IE9; quickly discover that jsFiddle doesn't work under IE8.  Post link to Fiddle anyway (see summary, above).

Look at stack again. I know that it fails when it enters the conditional starting at line 13952.  What is the value of dataLabel?  Hmmm... dataLabel.textAlign is a string whose value is the source of a function.  Where'd that come from?

Unfortunately, I don't know.  Everything still looks fine when it disappears into jQuery on the $el.animate() call on line 1408.  When it pops up in win.HighchartsAdapeter.init at line 1093, I can see that, in the case in which the requested function is '_default' that sometimes fx.now (fx is bound at line 1128) is this function string instead of a number. Since fx is being passed in from jQuery, I don't really know where it came from.

Since the function that the string represents appears to be in Highcharts, but fx comes from the jQuery animation logic, it seems likely that some component of Highcharts stringified the function and returned it to jQuery.  It also seems reasonable to suppose that this would happen in the adaptor.  I have no proof of this, but it seems a good place to start looking.

I have already looked for scoping errors around the use of the 'align' symbol, but haven't found anything.  There is some monkey-business going on at line 4024 that looks suspicious... yes, I can see that it gets invoked with key = 'align' and value = <stringified align() source> + 'NaN'.

The caller here is the attr() implementation of the adaptor (line 4539). The hash and val arguments both contain our (presumably) bad string.  Those values were passed in from line 1139 in init() which leads us back to jQuery again.  Deja vu.

So, it's a jQuery bug?  If so, why did it work with Highcharts v2.3.3?

I can see that the anonymous function in init() implements the _default() method employed by the jQuery animation step, but I still don't know why the step's 'now' member has this strange value. It's also evident that rotations are handled as a special case when applied to point labels, and that special care is being taken to avoid overwriting the SVG 'align' property.  jQuery 1.7+ also appears to be a distinct case, and the _default() adaptor is generated for jQuery 1.7+ only.

After looking at the jQuery documentation for the animate() function, my suspicion is that the whole problem is that the system is trying to animate the "align" property in the first place.  Animating a non-numeric value makes no sense to me, and the element appears to be malformed, inasmuch as the 'end' and 'now' properties have non-numeric values, and 'start' is missing entirely.

Apparently, 'align' is being animated because it is in the 'animatedProperties' collection of some object (not sure what it is), along with 'x' and 'y'.  The documentation for animate() seems to make it clear that animated properties must be numeric (seems perfectly reasonable to me).  What happens if I leave the 'rotation' property in my plotOptions.column.dataLabels setup, but remove 'align'?

Still breaks.

I'm going to stop digging here and ask the Highchart folks to take a look at this.

Comment: Why does your title say Highcharts 3.02?  I don't think there is any such version, and you yourself mention 3.0.1.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My bad.

Comment: I have finally been able to reproduce this problem in a test case. The key is that the problem does not occurr unless you call chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimate) with doAnimate = true.  See main body for code.

Comment: Nice investigation.  If you haven't already, I suggest you post an issue (bug) to their tracker on GitHub and link to here.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1821

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have found that an invalid argument is passed to the VMLRenderer.attr method. Add this log in the top of the function definition to see:
>
> attr: function (hash, val) {if (hash == 'align') { console.log('@attr ' + val); }
>
> This method is probably called from the animation logic.

The solution is:

```
// Don't run animations on textual properties like align (#1821)
if (fx.prop === 'align') {
  return;
}
```

**References**

- [Fixed issue with JS errors in IE8 when trying to animate a rotated data label](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/3ce48f886187c27f507fe3386fc48d1e63d6d8ca)